# VBA Solver Pasting Results Each Time

Tags: excel, vba, loops, solver

I've searched and searched and I cannot figure this out.  Any help is very much appreciated.

I'm running a basic simplex solver.  I'm looking to come up with the max number $A$4, based on projections (column H), and salary (column G).  My constraints are solid, but I cannot get it to loop, and then to paste the results somewhere.  The binary solution is in column A, a total of 6 results out of 200.  I have all of this data in "Optimizer 1", and want to paste the result each time in "List", starting in Cell A1-A6, then the second loop would be A7-A13, etc.  I want to do this 20 times.

The code I'm using now is:

```
For i = 0 To 20 Step 1
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
Calculate
SolverReset
SolverAdd CellRef:="$A$2:$A$201", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="binary"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$X$4", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$X$6"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$Z$4", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="$Z$6"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AE$3", Relation:=2, FormulaText:="$AF$3"
SolverAdd CellRef:="$AA$4", Relation:=1, FormulaText:=Worksheets("Optimizer 1").Range("$AA8").Offset(i, 0).Address
SolverOk SetCell:="$AA$4", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:=0, ByChange:="$A$2:$A$201", _
    Engine:=2, EngineDesc:="Simplex LP"
SolverSolve
SolverSolve (True)
SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

If i = 0 Then
Worksheets("List").Range("A1").Resize(6, 1).Value = _
    Worksheets("Optimizer 1").Range("b2:B201").Value

Else

Worksheets("List").Range("a1").End(xlUp).Offset(6).Resize(200, 1).Value = _
    Worksheets("Optimizer 1").Range("b2:b201").Value
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Once I have it in the "List", I have a vlookup to move it to another sheet "Lines", where it gives me the sum.  The first result is the most optimal, and then I want to find the second most, 3rd most, etc.

The other question I have is how can I make i (the times I loop) based on a cell?  I want to be able to change that if possible.

Hopefully someone can help.  This is my first time trying VBA.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you want 6 results or 200. Either way, here is a way to find the last row in column A and start the next loop on the next empty row.

```
Dim List_Current_row As Long
List_Current_row = Worksheets("List").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

If i = 0 Then
Worksheets("List").Cells(List_Current_row, 1).Resize(6, 1).Value = _
Worksheets("Optimizer 1").Range("b2:B201").Value

Else

Worksheets("List").Cells(List_Current_row,1).Resize(200, 1).Value = _
Worksheets("Optimizer 1").Range("b2:b201").Value
End If
Next i
```